# What does this `#((?<=\?)|&)openid\.[^&]+#` regexp mean?

Tags: php, regex

So I am triing to read some php code... I found such line

```
$uri = rtrim(preg_replace('#((?<=\?)|&)openid\.[^&]+#', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']), '?');
```

what does it mean?  and if it (seems for me) just returns 'file name' why it is so complicated?

Comment: it looks like it's removing the `?openid=xx` from the `REQUEST_URL` and putting the results into a new variable called `$uri`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The purpose of that line is to remove values like `openid.something=value` from the request URI.

There are tools out there to translate regex into prose, with an aim to help you understand what a regex is trying to match. For example, when yours is passed to [such a tool](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28%28%3F%3C%3D%5C%3F%29%7C%26%29%6F%70%65%6E%69%64%5C%2E%5B%5E%26%5D%2B) the description comes back as:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \?                       '?'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   |                        OR
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    &                        '&'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  openid                   'openid'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^&]+                    any character except: '&' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```

As the above says, the regex looks for a `?` or `&` followed by `openid.`, followed by anything not `&`. The resulting match will include the preceeding `&` if there is one, but not the `?` since a [look behind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) was used for the latter.